# GTK# and Wayland

Tags: c#, mono, gtk3, gtk#, wayland

I use GTK-Sharp3 under linux (ubuntu 22.04) to do some drawing :

```
context.SetSourceColor(color);
context.MoveTo(x1, y1);
context.LineTo(x2, y2);
context.Stroke();`
```

everything works well on xorg, but not with Wayland.
the DrawingArea does not update like on xorg. I have to switch to another window for the drawings to appear.
I think it's a bug, but is there a way to force this update without having to switch windows to force onDrawn?

thank you

I try to update manually the DrawingArea.
no results

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution:
DrawingArea.QueueDraw()

Comment: Nice that you found the answer, but usually people see into the GitHub repo first, https://github.com/GtkSharp/GtkSharp/discussions so you might consider posting future questions there to engage the user community.